# How to explain results after analyzing with clustMixType in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

k-prototypes was applied to my analysis towards data collected by questionnaires.

I haven't learn R and clustering yet but I'm trying to code while I met some problems when explaining the results I get 5 plots about different variables.

Furthermore, I don't know how to export the value.

Comment: I use clustMixType package.

Comment: Please see (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example] on how good questions are created. Furthermore a part of this question seems to be more suitable for http://stats.stackexchange.com/